# how can i know the number of student who has taken the prerequisites of a course?

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm trying to implement a query that selects the number of students that have taken the prerequisites of a certain course , i can implement it using a join statement if there is only one prerequisite for the course but in case of many prerequisites i'm facing trouble,
i have the following tables that are needed for this query

```
enroll(  Student_id,course_id,semester)
studyplan(major_id,course_id, creditHours)
prerequisite(course_id, prerequisite_id)
```

help please.. i'm running out of time.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: So basically you'd like us to do your homework and you are close to the deadline of which existence you just recalled. How about attaching your effort and clarifying the issue?

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two different RDBMS. Did you mean to tag both of them? If not then please edit your question to only tag the relevant one.

Comment: i'm sorry this is the first question i ask i don't know what should i consider..and this is not a home work this is  a bit of a bigger project i'm trying to make but i'm new to sql in general..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the `COLLECT` aggreagtion function and the `SUBMULTISET` operator.

**Oracle Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE Courses ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE Students ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE Enroll(
  Student_ID INT REFERENCES Students(ID),
  Course_ID  INT REFERENCES Courses(ID),
  Semester   DATE
);
CREATE TABLE StudyPlan(
  Major_ID     INT,
  Course_ID    INT REFERENCES Courses(ID),
  Credit_Hours INT
);
CREATE TABLE Prerequisite(
  Course_ID       INT REFERENCES Courses(ID),
  Prerequisite_ID INT REFERENCES Courses(ID)
);

INSERT INTO Courses
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

INSERT INTO Students
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;


INSERT INTO Prerequisite
SELECT 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 4 FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO Enroll
SELECT 1, 1, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 4, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE,  1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE,  1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 3, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 4, ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) FROM DUAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE INTLIST AS TABLE OF INT;
/
```

**Query**:

```
WITH prereq ( prerequisite_ids ) AS (
  SELECT CAST( COLLECT( prerequisite_id ) AS INTLIST )
  FROM   Prerequisite
  WHERE  Course_ID = :courseid
),
enrollments ( student_id, course_ids ) AS (
  SELECT student_id,
         CAST( COLLECT( course_id ) AS INTLIST )
  FROM   enroll
  WHERE  semester < TO_DATE( :semester, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
  GROUP BY student_id
)
SELECT student_id
FROM   prereq p
       INNER JOIN enrollments e
       ON ( p.prerequisite_ids SUBMULTISET OF e.course_ids );
```

**Output**:

The bind variables `courseid` and `semester` are `5` and `'2016-03-20'` respectively.

```
STUDENT_ID
----------
         3 
         5
```

Student 1 and 2 have not enrolled in the prerequisite courses. Student 4 has enrolled in the prerequisite courses but courses 3 and 4 have semester dates after the specified date so do not count. Students 3 and 5 have all the prerequisites and are output.

Comment: thanks for your help ..i tried the entire code but i'm getting (no rows selected)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but what determine is student have taken the prerequisites?
Probably the table prerequisite should have Student_id field...

```
select studyplan.course_id, count(Student_id)
from enroll, studyplan
where exists(select 1 from prerequisite where enroll.course_id = prerequisite.course_id)
and studyplan.course_id = enroll.course_id
group by studyplan.course_id
```

Comment: I get this error: `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`

Comment: i'm don't test in, but now should be ok.